# Django read data from list of QuerySets

Tags: python, django

I have the following list

```
[<QuerySet [{'number': 123}]>, <QuerySet []>, <QuerySet []>, <QuerySet [{'number': 21323}]>, <QuerySet []>]
```

I want to extract the numbers in an other list with a for loop and skip the empty QuerySets, but was not successful yet.
Is there an easy way?

Tahnk you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with:

```
[q['number'] for qs in qs_list for q in qs]
```

where `qs_list` is the list of `QuerySet`s.

That being said, often a list of `QuerySet`s means you are doing something inefficient, since you will here make a query per `QuerySet` in the list. Often you can derive the values all in the *same* query.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
Works perfectly.
Actually I'm pretty new to programming and Django. So I guess I'm doing a lot of unefficient stuff. 
But I try to improve every day.